# Filter multiple fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, webix

I have a "contacts" JSON file that has:
firstname
lastname
phone
address
zip
etc

I have a block of JS that works properly and filters based on ONE field:

```
{
  view: 'search',
  value: '',
  batch: 'list',
  on: {
    onTimedKeyPress: function () {
      $$('list').filter('lastname', this.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

How can I have it filter by using multiple (TWO) fields - for example, i want something along the lines of

```
$$('list').filter('lastname' || 'firstname', this.getValue());
```

(I realize this is not the right syntax, but am stumped?) How can I change that line of code to filter using two fields?

Comment: What library are you using? What is `$$`?

Comment: I'm not sure what library this is, but you can probably pass a function into the .filter() method that returns true if the item is to be included.

Comment: @NetTemple then Patrick is right. Go read [the docs](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.proto_filter.html). `filter` does accept a function as a first argument.

Comment: okay, i'll go read the docs... in the meantime, if any Webix experts see this, I would appreciate it if you weigh in with a comment or reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an JS expert, but I resolved this by using

```
                    $$("search").attachEvent("onTimedKeyPress",function(){ 
                      var value = this.getValue().toLowerCase(); 

                    $$("dataview").filter(function(obj){ 
                        var res = false;
                        if (obj.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value)!== -1 || obj.author.toLowerCase().indexOf(value)!== -1) res = true;
                        return res;
                    })
                });
```

Where title, author are my data fields.